# Interface for XML editor

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1qG6z6BbYQ

at 1:22, the way he edits the XML for resources is totally different from mine. Mine is only coding and his is more visual. Does he use a custom plugin?

Comment: To be honest i didn't watch the video but you might want to check DroidDraw. http://www.droiddraw.org/

Answer (score 2):

No it is the normal Eclipse with AndroidSDK.

The bar at the bottom you can choose between xml-View and "Layout" (which is the more "Visual")